# how to set octave x-axis limitation and interval

Tags: plot, octave

I want to plot a graph in octave in which the x-axis maximum value is 2048, and the they start with 0 and increment by 100. 
The y data is a vector of 2049 numbers.

here is my code :

`ydata = load ("data.txt"); 
x = linspace(1,2048,2048);
plot(x,ydata(:,1));`

this figures the x-axis with maximum value of 2500.

Comment: You don't need `linspace` there, you can do `x=1:2048`. But that is the default for `plot`, so just do `plot(ydata(:,1))`.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Silver's answer, you might also want to set the `XTick` property of the axes:

```
ydata = rand(2048,1);
plot(ydata(:,1))
xlim([0 2048])
set(gca,'XTick',0:100:2048)
```

This produces the following, which I think is what you're after (note the axis labels are a bit on top of each other but that's because you wanted them every 100 - changing the aspect ratio of the figure will help):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is xlim

```matlab
xlim([0 2048]);
```

That will limit the x-axes in the plot between 0 and 2048.
See the documentation [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/xlim.html) for more info.

Comment: I used it but the x axis still shows 2500, not 2048